# What does lexical error at '\a' mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: haskell, lexical

I am new to haskell and was trying to run the following bit of code, but somehow got this error:
lexical error at character '\a'. This error wasn't happening until I added the `let loop = do ...`.
(The line 9 comment isn't in the original code)
Code:

```
start :: IO ()
start = do
--  <- line 9
    let indices = listOptions [True, False, False, False, True, True, True]
    let loop = do
            putStrLn "---menu---"
            printOptions ["New game", "Load game", "Delete game", "Layouts", "Overview", "Refresh", "Leave"] indices
            putStr "Enter: "
            hFlush stdout
            choice <- getLine
            let input = case readMaybe choice :: Maybe Int of
                    Just a -> a
                    Nothing -> -1
            direct 0 input indices
    loop
```

Error:

```
main.hs:9:5: error: lexical error at character '\a'
  |
9 |     
  |     ^
```

Originally, the code on line 10 was on line 9, so I re-wrote the line on line 10 and deleted it thinking that would solve the problem. I also tried looking for what '\a' it see if that could help, but I was unable to find information on it. I even removed the empty line, so the `let indices = ...` is one line 9, but that didn't work either.

Hexdump:

```
6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 20 4d 65 6e 75 20 77 68 65 72
65 0d 0a 0d 0a 69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 53 79 73 74
65 6d 2e 49 4f 0d 0a 69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 53 79
73 74 65 6d 2e 45 78 69 74 28 65 78 69 74 53 75
63 63 65 73 73 29 0d 0a 69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 54
65 78 74 2e 52 65 61 64 0d 0a 0d 0a 73 74 61 72
74 20 3a 3a 20 49 4f 20 28 29 0d 0a 73 74 61 72
74 20 3d 20 64 6f 0d 0a 2d 2d 20 20 3c 2d 20 6c
69 6e 65 20 39 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 6c 65 74 20 69
6e 64 69 63 65 73 20 3d 20 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74
69 6f 6e 73 20 5b 54 72 75 65 2c 20 46 61 6c 73
65 2c 20 46 61 6c 73 65 2c 20 46 61 6c 73 65 2c
20 54 72 75 65 2c 20 54 72 75 65 2c 20 54 72 75
65 5d 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 6c 65 74 20 6c 6f 6f 70
20 3d 20 64 6f 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 2d 2d 2d
6d 65 6e 75 2d 2d 2d 22 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 70 72 69 6e 74 4f 70 74 69 6f
6e 73 20 5b 22 4e 65 77 20 67 61 6d 65 22 2c 20
22 4c 6f 61 64 20 67 61 6d 65 22 2c 20 22 44 65
6c 65 74 65 20 67 61 6d 65 22 2c 20 22 4c 61 79
6f 75 74 73 22 2c 20 22 4f 76 65 72 76 69 65 77
22 2c 20 22 52 65 66 72 65 73 68 22 2c 20 22 4c
65 61 76 65 22 5d 20 69 6e 64 69 63 65 73 0d 0a
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 75 74 53
74 72 20 22 45 6e 74 65 72 3a 20 22 0d 0a 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 68 46 6c 75 73 68
20 73 74 64 6f 75 74 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 63 68 6f 69 63 65 20 3c 2d 20 67
65 74 4c 69 6e 65 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 6c 65 74 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 3d 20
63 61 73 65 20 72 65 61 64 4d 61 79 62 65 20 63
68 6f 69 63 65 20 3a 3a 20 4d 61 79 62 65 20 49
6e 74 20 6f 66 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 4a 75 73 74 20
61 20 2d 3e 20 61 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 4e 6f 74 68
69 6e 67 20 2d 3e 20 2d 31 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 64 69 72 65 63 74 20 30 20
69 6e 70 75 74 20 69 6e 64 69 63 65 73 0d 0a 20
20 20 20 6c 6f 6f 70 0d 0a 0d 0a 6c 69 73 74 4f
70 74 69 6f 6e 73 20 3a 3a 20 5b 42 6f 6f 6c 5d
20 2d 3e 20 5b 49 6e 74 5d 0d 0a 6c 69 73 74 4f
70 74 69 6f 6e 73 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 62 6c
65 20 3d 20 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 48
65 6c 70 65 72 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 62 6c 65
20 31 0d 0a 0d 0a 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e
73 48 65 6c 70 65 72 20 3a 3a 20 5b 42 6f 6f 6c
5d 20 2d 3e 20 49 6e 74 20 2d 3e 20 5b 49 6e 74
5d 0d 0a 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 48 65
6c 70 65 72 20 28 61 70 70 20 3a 20 61 70 70 73
29 20 69 6e 64 65 78 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 7c 20 61
70 70 20 3d 20 69 6e 64 65 78 20 3a 20 6c 69 73
74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 48 65 6c 70 65 72 20 61
70 70 73 20 28 69 6e 64 65 78 20 2b 20 31 29 0d
0a 20 20 20 20 7c 20 6f 74 68 65 72 77 69 73 65
20 3d 20 2d 31 20 3a 20 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74 69
6f 6e 73 48 65 6c 70 65 72 20 61 70 70 73 20 69
6e 64 65 78 0d 0a 6c 69 73 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e
73 48 65 6c 70 65 72 20 5f 20 5f 20 3d 20 5b 5d
0d 0a 0d 0a 70 72 69 6e 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73
20 3a 3a 20 5b 53 74 72 69 6e 67 5d 20 2d 3e 20
5b 49 6e 74 5d 20 2d 3e 20 49 4f 20 28 29 0d 0a
70 72 69 6e 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 20 28 76 20
3a 20 76 73 29 20 28 69 6e 64 65 78 20 3a 20 69
6e 64 69 63 65 73 29 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 7c 20 69
6e 64 65 78 20 3d 3d 20 2d 31 20 3d 20 64 6f 0d
0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c
6e 20 24 20 22 58 2e 22 20 2b 2b 20 76 0d 0a 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 72 69 6e 74 4f 70 74 69
6f 6e 73 20 76 73 20 69 6e 64 69 63 65 73 0d 0a
20 20 20 20 7c 20 6f 74 68 65 72 77 69 73 65 20
3d 20 64 6f 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 75
74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20 24 20 28 73 68 6f 77 20 69
6e 64 65 78 29 20 2b 2b 20 22 2e 22 20 2b 2b 20
76 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 72 69 6e 74
4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 20 76 73 20 69 6e 64 69 63
65 73 0d 0a 70 72 69 6e 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73
20 5f 20 5f 20 3d 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 20 22 22
0d 0a 0d 0a 64 69 72 65 63 74 20 3a 3a 20 49 6e
74 20 2d 3e 20 49 6e 74 20 2d 3e 20 5b 49 6e 74
5d 20 2d 3e 20 49 4f 20 28 29 0d 0a 64 69 72 65
63 74 20 69 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 28 6f 70 74 69
6f 6e 20 3a 20 6f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 29 0d 0a 20
20 20 20 7c 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 3e 20 30 20 26
26 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 3d 3d 20 6f 70 74 69 6f
6e 20 3d 20 63 61 73 65 20 69 20 6f 66 0d 0a 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 2d 3e 20 70 75 74 53
74 72 4c 6e 20 22 31 22 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 31 20 2d 3e 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20
22 32 22 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 20 2d
3e 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 33 22 0d 0a
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 33 20 2d 3e 20 70 75 74
53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 34 22 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 34 20 2d 3e 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e
20 22 35 22 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 35 20
2d 3e 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 36 22 0d
0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 36 20 2d 3e 20 65 78
69 74 53 75 63 63 65 73 73 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 5f 20 2d 3e 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e
20 22 49 6e 76 61 69 6c 64 20 69 6e 70 75 74 22
0d 0a 20 20 20 20 7c 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 3c 20
30 20 3d 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 49 6e
76 61 69 64 20 69 6e 70 75 74 22 0d 0a 20 20 20
20 7c 20 6f 74 68 65 72 77 69 73 65 20 3d 20 64
69 72 65 63 74 20 28 69 20 2b 20 31 29 20 69 6e
70 75 74 20 6f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 0d 0a 64 69 72
65 63 74 20 5f 20 5f 20 5b 5d 20 3d 20 70 75 74
53 74 72 4c 6e 20 22 49 6e 76 61 6c 69 64 20 69
6e 70 75 74 22
```

Edit: I tried restarting my computer that that made the error go from line nine to line eight
Edit 2: I somehow managed to fix it. I went to the main function and commented out the `start` function call and printed "Hello", which gave another error with the same problem, then deleted the `putStrLn "Hello"` and uncommented the `start` function call. And it (somehow) started working again?!

Edit 3: I was using Notepad++, and bound the keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+h to run the script. I must've missed clicked and typed ctrl+shift+g, which types, presumably, 0x07 character.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Likely you entered some ASCII control character there. Copy the code from the StackOverflow post back in the editor.

Comment: I tried, but the error still persists

Comment: There's something weird going on with your editor / OS / locale. Show a hex-dump of your `.hs` file.

Comment: How do I upload a picture?

Comment: Don't upload a picture, open the file (the one you tried to compile) in a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor), copy the hexadecimal display and paste that. (Well, a screenshot of the hex editor would also be ok.) There are online hex editors if you don't have one installed, https://hexed.it/ seems nice.

Comment: 73 74 61 72 74 20 3a 3a 20 49 4f 20 28 29 0d 0a
73 74 61 72 74 20 3d 20 64 6f 0d 0a 2d 2d 20 20
3c 2d 20 6c 69 6e 65 20 39 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 6c
65 74 20 69 6e 64 69 63 65 73 20 3d 20 6c 69 73
74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 20 5b 54 72 75 65 2c 20
46 61 6c 73 65 2c 20 46 61 6c 73 65 2c 20 46 61
6c 73 65 2c 20 54 72 75 65 2c 20 54 72 75 65 2c
20 54 72 75 65 5d 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 6c 65 74 20
6c 6f 6f 70 20 3d 20 64 6f 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 75 74 53 74 72 4c 6e 20
22 2d 2d 2d 6d 65 6e 75 2d 2d 2d 22 0d 0a 20 20
20

Comment: No. I typed it, but I copied the code from the question

Comment: Your hex dump looks ok and does not contain any `'\a'` characters (that would be `07`). Are you sure this is the file you tried to compile? - BTW please always edit such information into the question, not into comments.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: "I tried restarting my computer that that made the error go from line nine to line eight" - ??? What cursed operating system is this? Your file is _ok_, based on the hexdump.

Comment: That would be Windows 11

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-g and Ctrl-shift-g would both be likely to insert ASCII 0x07. (In general, a common behavior is to insert an ASCII control character `n` when the control key is held down while typing a character with ASCII value `n + 64` (or `n | 0x40`).